# Difference between string_agg vs array_agg in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-aggregation

I think `string_agg` vs `array_agg` is almost same when one is return string type and another is return array type. Is there any other difference between them?

Which should I prefer? First or second?

```
array_agg(tag_name, ',') as Tag
```

OR

```
string_agg(tag_name, ',') as Tag
```

OR

```
array_to_string(array_agg(tag_name), ',') as Tag
```

Can anyone explain it for me? 1.array_agg 2. string_agg 3. array_to_string

Answer (score 3):

Your first expression stems from an era where Postgres didn't have `string_agg()` and shouldn't be used if you simply want a string (text) value.

Using `string_agg(tag_name, ',')` is the preferred way with modern Postgres versions if you want to concatenate string values.

---

You use `string_agg()` when you want a string value, and `array_agg()` when you want to work with an array.

Comment: Sorry I have edited the question. Please take a look at again.

Answer (score 1):

On your after-edited question, the first one throws an ERROR so you don't want that.

The 2nd and 3rd do the same thing, but the 3rd is gratuitously slow and memory intensive.